# Adding custom thumbnail previews

Tags: file-management, thumbnails

I am considering buying a tablet with Android, in order to navigate a particular kind of files. These files have .pes extension, and they are special files for embroidery machines, they contain the "instructions" to create particular images for the machine itself. The aim is to navigate those files using a file explorer app, for the customers of our shop: we would like to give a preview of the images in our catalogue before embroidering them. Obviously, thumbnail previews will be really useful, with no need to open every single image. But I am not able to find a single app which can provide a preview for "special" files, which are not jpeg, png, and similar.
Is there a way to customize or add the type of files for which the thumbnail previews are possible?

Comment: Explicitly asking for app recommendation is off topic here. Since PES isn't a standard image file, normal gallery apps (which show thumbnails) won't be able to handle the format. If none of the existing embroidery viewer apps fulfill your needs, you can get a simple app developed according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There IS a way of creating the picture files (which is what you want - a thumbnail is a small version of a picture file), but not the way you want to do it.  You'll have to use the .pes file to create the embroidery, using an embroidery machine, then take a picture of it.  (There's no way of "creating a thumbnail" from a list of instructions for an embroidery machine.)